# tar Cannot mkdir: No such file

Tags: tar

Running the following command I get error complaining Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory. I think it has something to do with the \ in the path name. how to work around this?

I run this on Centos.

```
tar xf dpdk-17.02.tar.xz
tar: dpdk-17.02/app/test/test_pci_sysfs/bus/pci/devices/0000\:01\:00.0: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
tar: dpdk-17.02/app/test/test_pci_sysfs/bus/pci/devices/0000\:01\:00.0: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
tar: dpdk-17.02/app/test/test_pci_sysfs/bus/pci/devices/0000\:01\:00.0/class: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: dpdk-17.02/app/test/test_pci_sysfs/bus/pci/devices/0000\:01\:00.0: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
tar: dpdk-17.02/app/test/test_pci_sysfs/bus/pci/devices/0000\:01\:00.0/config: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: dpdk-17.02/app/test/test_pci_sysfs/bus/pci/devices/0000\:01\:00.0: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory
tar: dpdk-17.02/app/test/test_pci_sysfs/bus/pci/devices/0000\:01\:00.0/consistent_dma_mask_bits: Cannot open: No such file or directory
```

I tried strace to get more details and here is the output on one of the errors:

```
mkdirat(AT_FDCWD, "dpdk-17.02", 0755)   = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
mkdirat(AT_FDCWD, "dpdk-17.02/app", 0755) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
mkdirat(AT_FDCWD, "dpdk-17.02/app/test", 0755) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
mkdirat(AT_FDCWD, "dpdk-17.02/app/test/test_pci_sysfs", 0755) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
mkdirat(AT_FDCWD, "dpdk-17.02/app/test/test_pci_sysfs/bus", 0755) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
mkdirat(AT_FDCWD, "dpdk-17.02/app/test/test_pci_sysfs/bus/pci", 0755) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
mkdirat(AT_FDCWD, "dpdk-17.02/app/test/test_pci_sysfs/bus/pci/devices", 0755) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
mkdirat(AT_FDCWD, "dpdk-17.02/app/test/test_pci_sysfs/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0", 0755) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "dpdk-17.02/app/test/test_pci_sysfs/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0", 0x7ffe85312de0, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "tar: ", 5)                    = 5
write(2, "dpdk-17.02/app/test/test_pci_sys"..., 79) = 79
write(2, ": No such file or directory", 27) = 27
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
write(2, "tar: ", 5)                    = 5
write(2, "dpdk-17.02/app/test/test_pci_sys"..., 85) = 85
```

Comment: for tar.xz use `tar xJvf` command.

Comment: I tried with xJvf and still get the same error.

Comment: It would be cool if you added the `strace` command you used

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to symlinks. It might be worth looking at what tar is doing via 'strace' (simply prefix the tar command with `strace`).

You should see from the strace output what tar is trying to do and failing at.

Comment: I tried strace and added the output to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I was performing the tar on my home directory which was on CIFS which follows Windows filename rules and limitations. Colon is not allowed in CIFS (Windows). I redid the same on a local partition and there was no problem.